# Can start 2 services from the same activity and can run that activity and two services parrallely in android?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have 2 services to get data from the accelerometer and microphone and 1 activity to get GPS data. I want to run these 3 things at the same time. I want to know is that possible in Android. While the GPS Activity running and display the data on the UI, other 2 services alse should run in the background.

If it is possible is the way correct that I gave to start two services from my GPS Activity class and run those 3 thing at the same time. Please any one hlp me. Thank you.

`

```
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    gpsManager = new GPSManager();

    gpsManager.startListening(getApplicationContext());
    gpsManager.setGPSCallback(this);

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.info_message)).setText(getString(R.string.info));

    measurement_index = AppSettings.getMeasureUnit(this);
    Intent i=getIntent();
     number=i.getStringExtra("NUMBER");
     startService(new Intent(GPS2Activity.this, GforceService.class));
     startService(new Intent(GPS2Activity.this,SPLService.class));



} `
```

`GforceService`  and `SPLService` are my 2 services

Comment: Yes, you can start 2 services and have them running in parallel with your Activities. Are you experiencing some problems with that?

Comment: great! I want to know the way that I gave is correct or not, because I have no experience in dealing with services.

Comment: OK, I created an answer for you. You can accept this answer if that is all you wanted to know.

Comment: your code **works if your platform 5.0.0 or 5.0.0+** othre wise you have to use receiver.

Comment: @devdattbhatt Your comment is wrong. This code works on all versions of Android. You can start as many Services as you want and they all run in parallel. What makes you think this doesn't work on older Android versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can start 2 services and have them running in parallel with your Activities.

Comment: a new question :), can I use AsyncTask in the services and so that the AsyncTask run in parallel, reason for me asking is since i have noticed that AsyncTask cant run in parallel in android 4.

Comment: @user1796624 You should probably post a new question for this. But `AsyncTask` is used to run background activities from the UI. Since a `Service` has no UI, it makes no sense to mix `AsyncTask` with `Service`. If you want parallel operations you can just use `Thread` and optionally a thread pool.

Comment: Will running two services be bad or memory inefficient?