# Are their any negatives impacts of launching two continues services at the same time? What are some alternatives if so?

Tags: android, performance, android-service

I am planning on having an activity with two check boxes. I want to do some tasks when the screen is off in the background continuously based on what the user check marks.

```
     final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
         if ( checkBox1.isChecked() && myServiceIsntRunning() ) {
         startService(myService1.class)

  if ( checkBox2.isChecked() && myService2IsntRunning() ) {
         startService(myService2.class)
         }
```

If both the checkmarks are checked, I wan't both tasks to constantly run in the background forever using this method. Is there any harm in launching both services at once? There doesn't appear to be any documentation about it in the Optimization tips documentation, and I saw this page about it: [Can start 2 services from the same activity and can run that activity and two services parrallely in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982424/can-start-2-services-from-the-same-activity-and-can-run-that-activity-and-two-se). So, would starting two services parallely forever be a good idea?

Comment: hm. what if you create 1 additional service that cover both task? so if checkbox 1 and 2 is checked then start myService3.class

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I have thought about that, but how would I merge them into one service? Because if I put if statements to check to see, it will run in order rather than at the same time. For example, if I have one big service would I say, "If checkbox one is checked, continue to run this code infinitely" and "If checkbox two is checked, continue to run this other code infinitely"? Because the second if statement would never get executed, and infinite loops are never good...How would I go about that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they do not conflict, it is OK to have more than one service running. Some battery life and memory may be affected, depending on your code. If possible, you can consider merging them to one service to handle 2 tasks.

Comment: Okay, how would I merge them into one service? Because if I put if statements to check to see, it will run in order rather than at the same time. For example, if I have one big service would I say, "If checkbox one is checked, continue to run this code infinitely" and "If checkbox two is checked, continue to run this other code infinitely"? Because the second if statement would never get executed, and infinite loops are never good...How would I go about that? Thanks!

Comment: I don't want the services to be destroyed, and I want two services to be `onForground`. How can I do that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168209/are-their-any-negatives-impacts-of-launching-two-continues-services-at-the-same